# Change angle radius in UI button

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I change UI button angle radius in Unity without Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: with Paint :P no, seriously: You have to use custom textures. Then you can use your custom roundings and readjust the slicing using the [SpriteEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the pixels per unit inside the texture import settings.

[image]

However, you still need to add your own texture as you're not allowed to modify Unity's default textures.